# Como hacer que un programa reciba y verifique un INT?

Tags: java, validación, while

tengo un problema con mi codigo que va de validacion de datos, consiste en que el usuario introduzca un cifra no mayor a 8 digitos y que si el usuario introduce una letra el programa la detecte y diga **Nada de letras**

este es mi codigo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner entradas = new Scanner(System.in); 
    int numero;
    do{
        numero = entradas.nextInt();
        
    }while(!entradas.hasNextInt());{
    System.out.println("nada de letras");
}
}
```

}

mi profesor me enseño que era algo asi, pero no se porque falla el codigo cuando introduzco una letra

Comment: No estoy seguro, pero si has declarado `numero` como `int` y lo primero que haces es intentar meter ahí lo primero que escribes, que es una letra... Deberías comprobar también antes de asignar nada que ahí haya un número.

Comment: En eso pense, pero los codigos que he visto utilizan if y cuando introduces un caracter de tipo letra el codigo falla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En primer lugar, el `do while` es solo esta parte:

```
do{
   numero = entradas.nextInt();
}while(!entradas.hasNextInt());
```

Las siguientes líneas quedan fuera del ciclo, no forman parte de una instrucción de selección como podría ser un `if`, `else` o `switch`. Simplemente es un bloque de código que no está asociado a nada en especial.

```
{
    System.out.println("nada de letras");
}
```

En segundo lugar, `hasNextInt()` te dice si en el flujo de entrada, el siguiente conjunto de caracteres es un entero válido. De modo que la siguiente llamada a `nextInt()` no generará ningún error. Por lo tanto, te interesa llamar primero a `hasNextInt()` y solo si devuelve verdadero, llamar a `nextInt()`.

Entonces el código te quedaría así:

```
Scanner entradas = new Scanner(System.in); 
int numero;
while(!entradas.hasNextInt()) {
    System.out.println("nada de letras");

    // Quizá pienses que la llamada a nextInt() debería ir aquí
    // Pero no, porque hasNextInt() te dijo que no hay un entero disponible
    // Si llamaras a nextInt() aquí obtendrías una excepción por esa razón
}

// La ejecución llega a este punto solo cuando hay un entero para leer.
// Por lo tanto se lee aquí.
numero = entradas.nextInt();
```

Falta algo más. Si no se consume la información en el flujo de entrada, permanecerá ahí y `hasNextInt()` seguirá devolviendo el mismo valor. Si fuese falso, obtendrías un ciclo infinito.

---

Puedes consumir la entrada de dos maneras:

- Con la función `next`, ya que naturalmente la entrada contiene un `String` por lo que no habrá errores de lectura por tipos incorrectos.
- Con la función `skip` que saltará la entrada que coincida con el patrón indicado.

Con `next` te quedaría así:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner entradas = new Scanner(System.in); 
    int numero;

    while(!entradas.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("nada de letras");
        entradas.next();
    }

    numero = entradas.nextInt();
}
```

Y `skip` lo puedes usar con la expresión regular [`\D`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) que corresponde a cualquier caracter no numérico. Aunque saltará cada caracter individualmente, imprimiendo *nada de letras* por cada uno.

Tendrás que recurrir a una que comprenda varios por ejemplo `\n*[^\d\n]*` que ignora todos los saltos de línea excepto el último y los caracteres no numéricos que haya en medio.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner entradas = new Scanner(System.in); 
    int numero;

    while(!entradas.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("nada de letras");
        entradas.skip("\\n*[^\\d\\n]*");
    }

    numero = entradas.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: Te faltó una opción... `entradas.nextLine();` que en vez de saltarse el siguiente bloque se saltaría todo hasta el siguiente intro, no estoy seguro de si `next()` incluye también los saltos de línea.

Comment: @Benito-B `next()` consume el siguiente token. Si tuvieras de entrada `abc 123\n`, `nextLine()` se saltaría el 123. Mientras que `next()` no. Si no te importa perder un número puedes usarlo.